# In python/selenium, how to get Amazon web page item ratings information

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriverwait

In python/selenium, I want to get the item star in Amazon web page, but failed .Anyone can help ? Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


prefs = {
            'profile.default_content_setting_values': {
                'images': 2,
            }
        }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

chrome_options.add_argument('lang=en')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09VDD8D8R')
page_star = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-icon-alt")
page_star_text = page_star.text
# the wished result of page_star_text is "4.1 out of 5 stars"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rating text `4.1 out of 5 stars`, Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `presense of element located` and since the node value is hidden instead `.text` use `get_attribute("textContent")`

```
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09VDD8D8R")
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.a-icon-alt"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

console output:

[image]